# For loop to vector formation for performance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector

I have a some trouble with handling for loop to vector formation in Matlab.
That's image processing part.(about controling the light)
My orignal soruce code is bellow.

```
for i=1:1:p1
    for j=1:q1
        if A(i,j) <=25
            A(i,j) =0;
        end
    end
end
```

How can I change this code to vector for performance?
I already checked this url(https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Comment: I'd recommend having a read of how logical variables are used in [this documentation page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use logical indexing:

```
I = A<=25;
```

is a logical array that is `true` where `A` is smaller or equal to 25. You can use this array to index into A:

```
A(I) = 0;
```

sets the elements of `A` to `0` where `I` is true.

This can all be written as a single statement:

```
A(A<=25) = 0;
```

[I'm sure this has been asked before here, but I can't find any duplicates.]